# Show GroupItems in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, shapes

I am using this code to show the group number, how can I show the groupitems number?

```
Public Sub Shapename()
  MsgBox (Selection.ShapeRange.Name)
End Sub
```

Is there an easy way to figure out the shape names and numbers in Word?

Answer (score 0):

That would be the ZOrderPosition property:

```
Public Sub Shapename()
  MsgBox (Selection.ShapeRange.Name & " " & Selection.ShapeRange.ZOrderPosition)
End Sub
```